# Display all the table records whose count is greater than 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has category and brand as follows:

```
| id| category | brand |   date    | ........
| 1 |   A      | A1    | 12-DEC-09 | ........
| 1 |   A      | A1    | 12-DEC-09 |........
| 1 |   A      | A1    | 13-DEC-09 |........
| 2 |   A      | A2    | 14-DEC-09 |........
| 2 |   B      | B1    | 14-DEC-09 |........
| 2 |   B      | B2    | 14-DEC-09 |........
| 2 |   B      | B3    | 14-DEC-09 |........
```

I need to display the result with brand more than 1. The brand is based on category.

I need result like this:

```
| 1 |   A      | A1    | 12-DEC-09 | ......
| 1 |   A      | A1    | 12-DEC-09 |........
| 1 |   A      | A1    | 13-DEC-09 |........
```

I am only get category, brand and its total number with my query.

```
select
    category,
    brand,
    count(*) as total
from
    tbl_category
group by category, brand
```

But I need the result like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select c.*
from (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by category, brand) as cnt
      from tbl_category c
     ) c
where cnt > 1;
```